# Java threads in JNI C++ environment using only one core. Arm Processor and Ubuntu

Tags: java, c++, multithreading, java-native-interface, arm

I have made multithreaded java program for processing data from files. This is well tested, and distributes the work load on available cpu cores.

Now I have made a native reader in C++. This program is started from within Java using JNI, and calls the java program when data is ready.

The mechanism works well besides only one core is used for the entire java program when the native reader is activated.

I suspect the C++ reader is not compiled right, or maybe some problems with JNI shared memory.

I have tried several compiler and linker options for the C++ program: -pthread -lpthread -std=c++11

The platform is: Jetson TK1 with Arm processor. Java Oracle 1.8. OS Ubuntu.

Thank you for any answer.

Comment: Do you create a new thread in Java before jni-calling into c++ reader ?

Comment: An SSCCE might be helpful here: http://sscce.org/ It would make it much easier for other programmers to understand what your code actually does (Assuming, of course, that you don't find the answer for yourself while preparing the SSCCE.)

Comment: Than you Jojje, good suggestion! The JNI function into c++ is indeed called from a separate thread. The c++ program is a small never ending loop (with a small sleep) pushing data back into the java framework. So the original Thread in Java (spawning the C++ program) is hanging until the java program quits. Which is ok i guess.

Comment: I found out now that this has nothing to do with JNI or shared memory. The JNI c++ driver is using a third party library. All is fine until a function is called in this third party sw.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved!

The problem was new threads spawned from other processing threads, when needed. (Lazy starting of threads)
This work great when reading from a file when all threads are java based.

In this case the new java thread was spawned from a thread originating from C++ through JNI. I dont know exactly why, but in this case new threads ended up running on the same core.

The solution was to start the threads when the processing units where added to framework in java.
Now all cpu cores are utilized!

Thank you again Jojje! I think you got it with your comment!